# How far to go with typedef'ing primitive types like int

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have seen C++ code such as the following with many `typedef`s.

What are the benefits of using many `typedef`s like this as opposed to using C++ primitives? Is there another approach that might also achieve those benefits?

In the end, the data is all stored in memory or transmitted over the wire as bits and bytes, does it really matter?

```
types.h:

typedef int16_t Version;
typedef int32_t PacketLength;
typedef int32_t Identity;
typedef int32_t CabinetNumber;
typedef int64_t Time64;
typedef int64_t RFID;
typedef int64_t NetworkAddress;
typedef int64_t PathfinderAddress;
typedef int16_t PathfinderPan;
typedef int16_t PathfinderChannel;
typedef int64_t HandsetSerialNumber;
typedef int16_t PinNumber;
typedef int16_t LoggingInterval;
typedef int16_t DelayMinutes;
typedef int16_t ReminderDelayMinutes;
typedef int16_t EscalationDelayMinutes;
typedef float CalibrationOffset;
typedef float AnalogValue;
typedef int8_t PathfinderEtrx;
typedef int8_t DampingFactor;
typedef int8_t RankNumber;
typedef int8_t SlavePort;
typedef int8_t EventLevel;
typedef int8_t Percent;
typedef int8_t SensorNumber;
typedef int8_t RoleCode;
typedef int8_t Hour;
typedef int8_t Minute;
typedef int8_t Second;
typedef int8_t Day;
typedef int8_t Month;
typedef int16_t Year;
typedef int8_t EscalationLevel;
```

It seems logical to try and make sure the same type is always used for a particular thing to avoid overflows, but I do often see code where "int" has just been used pretty much everywhere instead.  The `typedef`ing often does lead to code that looks a bit like this though:

```
DoSomething(EscalationLevel escalationLevel) {
    ...
}
```

Which then makes me wonder which token is actually describing the parameter: the parameter type or the parameter name?

Comment: IMHO, seems like a pretty pointless exercise, but I'm sure some others would disagree...

Comment: Those types look like variable names.

Comment: Note that this creates the impression that it's type-safe, but it not at all - the typedefs just create aliases, but nothing stops you from passing for example a `Minute` to a function that has an argument declared as type `Second`.

Comment: Will `int16_t` be enough to store the year? What if scientists need to store years of prehistoric events? Also, why signed types for minute, hour, day, etc.?

Comment: @Chris Lutz: True if I was going to use the same typedefs for every project.. this is a single project where the Year will never be that far in the future.

Comment: @Mark: look at it another way. If you make a mistake deciding the integer type, or new requirements emerge in future, and so you want to change it, would you like to change a single typedef or would you like to search the code for every function that manipulates a year, and change its signature? 640k is enough for anyone, and all that. The corresponding downside to the typedef is that people accidentally or deliberately write code that relies on the fact that Year is exactly 16 bits, then it changes and their code breaks.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I can't decide if you think it's a good or bad idea :-)  The first part seems to be in favour, the latter against.  I guess it has pros and cons then.

Comment: For a Java developer, `DoSomething(EscalationLevel escalationLevel)
{
    ...
}` doesn't look strange at all (exect that it should read `doSomething`)

Comment: @Mark: indeed. I would say to use the typedef if there is *genuine* need for flexibility as to what the underlying type should be, as for example with `time_t`. Unfortunately it's sometimes difficult to decide whether there's genuine need. And if you're going to use them at all, you could also consider whether maybe your two types with "Address" in them should actually share a typedef, etc. If there's no genuine need, then don't impose upon your API's clients the burden of writing code that will work correctly with any integer type.

Comment: I guess one reason to specify type size is when it comes to serializing, the type itself determines how it is represented in a binary stream (2 bytes for int16_t, etc).  Mind you, that's more a question on int vs int16_t etc.. than whether to typedef the primitive types themselves.  (EDIT: Sorry I mean the appropriate function is called based on the type itself).

Comment: I'm still not sure which side to take. Probably it just depends on the details. At least I want to add that a typedef won't always double information. Using a typedef can add helpful information in the following case:
`EscalationLevel DoSomething() {
    ...
}` is more clear than 
`int DoSomething() {...}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The name of a parameter should describe what it means - in your case the escalation level. The type is how the value is represented - adding typedefs as in your example obfuscates this part of the function-signature, so I would not recommend it.

Typedefs are useful for templates, or if you want to change the type used for certain parameters, for instance when migrating from a 32bit to a 64bit platform.

Comment: This seems to be the general consensus then.  So would you generally just stick to "int"?  I have to be very efficient in this app when it comes to transfering data, so would it be a case of just convert to int16_t (or whatever the largest representation type needed for a particular element) during serialization?

Comment: @Mark: Yes, that is how you should do it. Use typedefs to express the size of the used data-types, but do not differentiate the same type used in different contexts.

Comment: Thanks - and just to clarify, you wouldn't bother using int8_t instead of int generally in the code..  I suppose my main worry was something like "Identity" which is actually a identity generated by a database.  At the moment it is 32bit but I'm not sure yet if that may eventually become 64bit.  Also, how about int32_t vs int?  int is *usually* the same as int32_t, but it might not always be I guess on a different platform?  I'm thinking I should just stick to "int" generally, and "int64_t" where neccessary.. thanks :-)

Comment: @Mark: The important thing about typedefs like `int32_t` is that you have to make sure they are correct when compiling on different platforms. If you expect the range of `Identity` to change at some point, I think I would prefer to make the changes directly in all affected code. But I am not sure, because I would need to know more about your specific design. You might want to make that a separate question.

Answer (score 17):

At first I thought "Why not" but then it occurred to me that if you're going to go to such lengths to separate the types like that, then make better use of the language. Instead of using aliases, actually define types:

```
class AnalogueValue
{
public:
    // constructors, setters, getters, etc..
private:
    float m_value;
};
```

There is no performance difference between:

```
typedef float AnalogueValue;
AnalogValue a = 3.0f;
CallSomeFunction (a);
```

and:

```
AnalogValue a (3.0f); // class version
CallSomeFunction (a);
```

and you also have the advantages of adding parameter validation and type safety. For example, consider code that deals with money using primitive types:

```
float amount = 10.00;
CallSomeFunction(amount);
```

Aside from the rounding issues, it also allows any type that can be converted to a float:

```
int amount = 10;
CallSomeFunction(amount);
```

In this case it is not a big deal, but implicit conversions can be a source of bugs that is difficult to pin down. Using a `typedef` does not help here, since they are merely a type alias.

Using a new type entirely means there are no implicit conversions unless you code a casting operator, which is a bad idea specifically because it allows implicit conversions. You can also encapsulate additional data:

```
class Money {
  Decimal amount;
  Currency currency;
};

Money m(Decimal("10.00"), Currency.USD);
CallSomeFunction(m);
```

Nothing else will fit into that function unless we write code to make it happen. Accidental conversions are impossible. We can also write more complex types as needed without much hassle.

Comment: You could even write some horrible macro to do all of this class creation for you. (Come on, Skizz. You know you want to.)

Comment: For some of these, a type-safe units library might be helpful (http://tuoml.sourceforge.net/html/scalar/scalar.html), rather than writing a custom class for each.

Comment: @Chris - Definitely not a macro, but possibly a template class.  As Steve points out, those classes are already written.

Comment: @Chris: The macro is called `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` actually ;)

Answer (score 4):

Using typedefs for primitive types like that looks more like C style code.

In C++ you will get interesting errors as soon as you try to overload functions for, say, `EventLevel` and `Hour`. That makes the extra type names pretty useless.

Answer (score 3):

We (at our company) do it a lot in C++. It helps understanding and maintaining code. Which is good when moving people between teams or doing refactoring. Example:

```
typedef float Price;
typedef int64_t JavaTimestmap;

void f(JavaTimestamp begin, JavaTimestamp end, Price income);
```

We believe it's a good practice to create typedef to the dimension name from the representation type. This new name represents a *general role* in a software. The name of a parameter is a *local role*. Like in `User sender, User receiver`. At some places it can be redundant, like `void register(User user)`, but I don't consider it being a problem.

Later one may have the idea that `float` is not the best for representing prices because of the special rounding rules of booking, so one downloads or implements a `BCDFloat` (binary coded decimal) type and changes the typedef. There is no search and replace work from `float` to `BCDFloat` which would be hardened by the fact that there are possibly many more floats in your code.

It is not a silver bullet and has its own caveats, but we think it is much better using it than not.

Comment: Or as Mathieu M. suggested at the post of Skizz one can go like `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(float, Price)`, but I wouldn't go that far on an average project. Or maybe I would. I have to sleep on it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`typedef` basically allows you to give an alias for an `type`.
It gives you the flexibility of avoiding typing the long `type names` again and again and making your `type` more easily readable wherein the alias name indicates the intent or purpose of the `type`.

It's more of an matter of choice if you wish to have more readable names through `typedef` in your project.
Usually, I avoid using `typedef` on primitive types, unless they are unusually long to be typed. I keep my parameter names more indicative.

Answer (score 1):

Using typedefs like this is okay as long as whoever winds up using them *doesn't need to know anything about their underlying representation*.  For example, if you want to pass a `PacketLength` object to either `printf` or `scanf`, you'll need to know its actual type so you can pick the right conversion specifier.  In cases like that, the typedef just adds a level of obfuscation without buying anything in return; you might as well have just defined the object as `int32_t`.

If you need to enforce semantics specific to each type (such as allowable ranges or values), then you're better off creating an abstract data type and functions to operate on that type, rather than just creating a typedef.

Answer (score 0):

I would never do something like this. Making sure they all have the same size is one thing- but you only need to refer to them as integral types, then.